# mvc view object best practice

Tags: java, oracle, model-view-controller, oracle-adf

We are currently working on an MVC proof of concept and are struggling with trying to decide what would be the best approach for dealing with "views" of information where we need to join two sources. (Primarily Oracle ADF)

So for example if you have employees, departments, property and property location would it be better to create the views you need in the DB, by View Link, by Read-Only SQL View Object, etc.

In the case where you would be updating information creating an association between entities would make sense, but in most of our scenarios all we need is the information from the relationship(s).

Any thoughts / comments /advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for associations that are equ-joins, then doing it in the database is preferred.
For master-detail models, you will want to create a link between the VO in ADF.
This is needed so that the JSF/ADF Faces components can connect to the hierarchical or structured data controls properly (tables, tress, etc)